# Camera won't follow Prefab C#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I used Brackeys tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MFQhpwc6cKE&t=211s My question is when I made my `GameObject` a Prefab and `Itempooled` using `SetActive()` My camera broke and now focuses on the world coordinates 0,0. What can I do to have the camera follow the GameObject again?

```
public Transform target;

public float smoothSpeed = 0.125f;
public Vector3 offset;

public GameObject scopeOverlay;

public GameObject Camera;

private Vector3 initialPosition;
private Quaternion initialRotation;

private void Start ()
{
    // Save initial transform values
    initialPosition = transform.position;
    initialRotation = transform.rotation;
}

void FixedUpdate ()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown("d"))
    {
        Camera.SetActive(false);
        scopeOverlay.SetActive(true);
        Vector3 desiredPosition = target.position + offset;
        Vector3 smoothedPosition = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, desiredPosition, smoothSpeed);
        transform.position = smoothedPosition;

        transform.LookAt(target);

    }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown("e"))
    {
        // Restore transform values
        transform.position = initialPosition;
        transform.rotation = initialRotation;

        Camera.SetActive(true);
        scopeOverlay.SetActive(false); //To disable it
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not initialize target, has this been set via the unity interface?
Futhermore I would advice looking for help on unity's own dedicated unity3d community, they have most likely more experience with these topics.
Perhaps this is of use https://answers.unity.com/questions/54247/camera-focusing-on-an-object-specified-in-a-script.html